# Firestore query returns documents which fields doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named ABC and when I am running the following query in node(12 OR 14) it also returns documents which "r_o" doesn't exist in it.

```
const aRef = firebase.collection('ABC');
let querysnap = await aRef.where('r_o', '!=', false).limit(50).get();
```

I have around 900K documents in the 'ABC' collection. Most don't have the field at all, some have it with a value of true(boolean), So in most of the documents "r_o" doesn't exist at all and the query should not return those documents but it does.

So looks like the query ignores ('r_o', '!=', false) and simply returns all 900K documents in the collection.

To clarify, I want to get all the documents only and IF only the field value is true, I don't want to have the documents if the field value is false OR field doesn't exist.

Per firebase documentation and in their example:

```
citiesRef.where("capital", "!=", false);
```

This query does not return
city documents where the `capital` field does not exist. Not-equal (!=)
and not-in queries exclude documents where the given field does not
exist.

---

PS: I am using package firebase-admin v9.0.0

Comment: So you say that the above query returns all documents in "ABC" collection  in which the `r_o` field doesn't hold the value of false and the documents that doesn't have the field at all?

Comment: Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: "So you say that the above query returns all documents in "ABC" collection in which the r_o field doesn't hold the value of false and the documents that doesn't have the field at all?": Yes, correct. That is what is happening. Through the console it returns only 400 documents which the value is true(This is what I want).

Comment: So you only want all documents hold the value of true and if it doesn't exist, right?

Comment: No and thank you for your replies, to clarify, I want to get all the documents only and IF only the field value is true, I don't want to have the documents if the field value is false OR field doesn't exist.

Comment: Understood. Can you please show us an example of a document that doesn't hold the `r_o` field and it is present in the results?

Comment: I find out if I remove limit clause, it only pulls correct documents. About example of a document, I am not sure how you would like me to add here since each document has a lots of fields and it is not east to copy and paste fields/Data here.